# What should be done with the questions that ask about the reason behind adjective order?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

There are a bunch of questions that ask about adjective order, and most of them are closed as dupes of the original [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order?noredirect=1&lq=1) asked 12+ years ago.

There are three questions that I'm concerned about:

- [What is the reason behind the royal order of adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333362/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-royal-order-of-adjectives) [Q1]
- [What is the reason for the 'royal' order of adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523085/what-is-the-reason-for-the-royal-order-of-adjective)?  [Q2]
- [Why do we order our adjectives in certain ways: "big, blue house" rather than "blue, big house"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599423/why-do-we-order-our-adjectives-in-certain-ways-big-blue-house-rather-than-b) [Q3]

All of these questions ask about the *reason* and the *history* of the rules, not just the specifics of them- they shouldn't have been closed as duplicates, though some comments say that they may be too linguistic in nature for EL&U.

Until today, the status of the three questions stood as follows:

- [Q1] was closed as a duplicate of the old original question
- [Q3] was closed as a duplicate of the old original question
- [Q2] was closed as a duplicate of [Q3], even though it's older than [Q3]

Today, [Q1] was re-opened. I edited [Q3] and added it to review with the intention of having it re-closed as a duplicate of [Q1], after which we might get the order:

`[Q2] is a dupe of [Q3] which is a dupe of [Q1]`

Note: [Q3] has not yet been re-closed as a duplicate of [Q1]. I've added this goal in the edit summary, we'll see if it works out that way.

I'm posting this meta-question in order to clarify my intent, as well as to seek input: Does this sound like the right way to go about resolving the confusion? Is there any other established guideline to use?

---

Edit: Turns out that questions can't be closed as dupes of questions without answers, which means that [Q1] has to be closed as a dupe of [Q3].

`[Q1] and [Q2] are both dupes of [Q3]`

This seems a little unfair because [Q3] is the newest to be posted, so if anyone can figure out a way around this, please share.

[Q3] and [Q1] are both open right now.

Comment: Note that moderators (and gold tag badge holders) can edit the list of duplicates so that both closed duplicates point to each other too.

Comment: Note that -you- can vote to close Q3 as a duplicate of Q1... _tries to vote to close as duplicate_ ... Oh. Hm... no you can't, and nobody can. Just try it. (Q1 has no answers and presumably the system only allows it to be the original if it has at least one upvoted answer). So maybe you should rethink your dupe ordering.

Comment: Ever elusive are the whys and wherefores of natural language regulations.

Comment: @Mitch - I didn't realize there was such a restriction. I wonder if tag-badge holders can.

Comment: Are you assuming here that the chronology should be the overriding consideration in what is a duplicate of what? It seems to me that it would be much more helpful to close as duplicates the questions with no answers or with not-very-good answers, and leave open the one with the best answers (regardless of whether it is the earliest).

Comment: @jsw29 - I just thought it was unfair to do so, and perhaps that's because one of the questions involved is my own, but you're also right. Maybe not the _overriding_ consideration, but I think it should be one.

Comment: Is there an answer to the reason for adjective order? If there isn't, just say so and close them all. We don't owe anybody speculation.

Comment: When, as in this case, there is a cluster of duplicates, I think that, however one decides what the 'original' is, it is important that all the duplicates point **directly** to the original. It is frustrating to those who land on a particular page to be told that the question is a duplicate of X, only to then, when they come to X, be told that it is a duplicate of Y, etc.

Comment: @JohnLawler David Adger has a reason/theory that he's published somewhere, I believe.

Comment: What, only one theory? Is this linguistics?

Comment: @JohnLawler English linguistics.

Comment: Questions about reason are a bit problematic although probably shouldn't be disallowed unless there's a clear attempt to provide a *reason* in one of the earlier questions. Questions about the history of the rules (either "Have the rules changed?" or even "Who first noticed the rules?") seem entirely proper, and separate questions. But closing may be justified as this is partly a problem of badly formulated questions: people asking "why?" in the manner of small children, without understanding the different types of explanations that are possible or considering what they actually want to know.